$H(X) = H(Y) \stackrel{?}{\implies} H(f(X)) = H(f(Y))$ for a determinsitic function $f$
I want to prove that if the entropy of two random variables, defined on the same space, is the same, then the entropy of any deterministic function of the respective random variables will also have the same entropy, i.e
$$H(X) = H(Y) \stackrel{?}{\implies} H(f(X)) = H(f(Y))$$
for a determinsitic function $f$, where $H$ is the entropy function, defined as $H(X) = -\sum_{x} P(X = x) \log_2 P(X = x)$
Now, let's consider $H(f(X))$:
$$H(f(X)) = -\sum_{f(x)} P(f(x)) \log_2 P(f(x))$$
Since $f$ is a deterministic function, $P(f(x)) = P(f(y))$ if $x = y$.
So, we can rewrite $H(f(X))$ as:
$$H(f(X)) = -\sum_{f(x)} P(x) \log_2 P(x)$$
Similarly, $H(f(Y))$ becomes:
$$H(f(Y)) = -\sum_{f(y)} P(y) \log_2 P(y)$$
Since $f$ is deterministic, $f(x) = f(y)$ if $x = y$, so the sum in both $H(f(X))$ and $H(f(Y))$ will be identical.
Is this argument okay? thanks in advance.

Your argument is not ok.
You already start with the false claim
$$H(f(X)) = -\sum_{f(x)} P(f(x)) \log_2 P(f(x))$$
What should the probability of a number be? The notation $P(f(x))$ is nonsense.
What you want to proove is false anyway, so nothing can be proven here.
Let $P(X=-1) = P(X=1) = \frac{1}{2} = P(Y=0) = P(Y=1)$, then $H(X) = H(Y) = 1$.
Now consider $f(x) = x^2$.

No, of course by $P(f(x))$ I meant $\Pr(f(X) = f(x))$. And thanks for such a simple counterexample.

Yes, but still your equation holds false, because multiple $x$ can lead to the same value of $f(x)$ and then you count values twice…
